# Limit returned entries per user per query

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have the following request:

```
let artPerCall = 20
let artPerUser = 2
let start = req.params.page

let query = `
    SELECT * from 
    (
        SELECT a.*, row_to_json(u.*) as userinfo,
            row_number() over (partition by u.address order by a.date desc) as ucount
        FROM artworks a INNER JOIN users u ON a.address = u.address 
        WHERE a.flag != ($1) OR a.flag IS NULL
    ) t
    WHERE ucount <= ($2)
    ORDER BY date DESC 
    LIMIT ${artPerCall} OFFSET ${(start-1) * artPerCall}`

pool.query(query, ["ILLEGAL", artPerUser])
    .then(users => {
        if (users) {
            res.json(users.rows);
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        next(err);
    })
```

Called through an API with the following path `/artworks/paginate/1/20` where (`/artworks/paginate/{page}/20`)

The expected result is to get 20 results per call with a maximum of 2 entries per user.

The current result:
It seem that it return only 2 entries per user as expected but once it return 2 for a user on a page then no more result for the same user in the following pages even if they have entries.

Any idea what i'm missing?

Comment: Any chance the page param can be zero? Just guessing here as I don't have my work setup, but would a negative offset cause this?

Comment: `LIMIT / OFFSET` is processed after the resultset of the underlying query has been formed. So this is to be expected. Add create table statements and example data with expected output to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seem that it return only 2 entries per user as expected but once it return 2 for a user on a page then no more result for the same user in the following pages even if they have entries.

Correct, this is what the query does. It selects:

```
row_number() over (partition by u.address order by a.date desc) as ucount
...
WHERE ucount <= ($2)
```

If parameter $2 is set to 2 as it is in your example code, then it will select 2 entries per user, not more, before sorting and pagination. If the user has more entries they will be filtered out.

If you remove "WHERE ucount <= ($2)" then you'll simply get all the results ordered by date, but that doesn't sound like what you want.

However, what I think you want to achieve sounds a bit complicated. I'm not sure either it would be great for usability as the results would look quite random to the user. So you will need to describe exactly what you want, with example data.

For example, if you want to avoid one user posting a lot of items with the same date pushing all the other users down in the search results, limiting the number of results per user is a good idea, but perhaps a button "more from this user..." would be a better choice than pushing the users' items down to the next pages.

Suppose you have only two users, user1 posts 20 items with date "today" and user2 posted 10 items yesterday. Do you want 2 items from user1, then 2 items from user2, then the 18 remaining items from user1, then the 8 remaining items from user? Or will they be interleaved with each other somewhat, which will make the date order a bit random in the results?

**EDIT**

Here's a proposal:

```
SELECT * from 
(
    SELECT *, 
        row_number() over (partition by user_id order by date desc) as ucount
    FROM artworks
) t
ORDER BY (ucount/3)::INTEGER ASC, date DESC 
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;
```

"(ucount/3)::INTEGER" is 0 for the first two artworks of each user, then 1 for the next 3, then 2 for the next 3, etc. So the most recent 2 artworks of each user end up first, then the most recent 3 artworks of each user, etc.

Another one:

```
ORDER BY ucount<3 ASC, date DESC
```

This will put the most recent 2 artworks of each user first, then the rest is simply sorted by date.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes this is exactly what i want, avoid users that post a lot to push others down and occupy all the space, here an example of the app:

https://mainnet.sign-art.app/

I don't want more than 2 entries per user every 20 entries for example

Comment: OK, so the results are presented as images, which means you don't actually care that much about the ordering by date, right? That's an important point

Comment: I actually do as it is ordered by the posted timestamp with most recent first. Is it more difficult to achieve if i want keep it date ordered?

Comment: Can you post an anonymized version of the artworks table on a file upload site? Just these columns: primary key, date, user_id (obfuscated if necessary)

Comment: Is this in cvs ok? 

Order: txid (primary key), address (user_id), timestamp

https://www.file.io/download/eFx2dvOBAGzL

The address is primary key in the user table.

Comment: Yes, it's fine. Only 29 rows in the table? That won't tell much about how fast the query is lol

Comment: Thats from the test app with testing data only. I can send the prod version but its only 400 entries, its a fairly new project. But needs to change all addresses to not just trop user data like that,

Comment: I've added stuff in the answer, tell me what you think.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's late here but i'll test asap tomorow morning and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hello, ok it seem to do the work pretty well, thank you very much :)